# Count a concatenated field

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, concatenation

The following query is an attempt to find multiple occurrences of a concatenated field:

```
SELECT ID, NUM1, NUM2, CONCAT(NUM1, NUM2)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID, NUM1, NUM2, CONCAT(NUM1, NUM2)
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(NUM1, NUM2) > 1
```

I am currently getting a list of records with COUNT(NUM1) > 1. How can I successfully query the count of a concatenated field?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating two instances of TABLE, linked by NUM1 and NUM2 separately, and inserted a ID_A != ID_B row. Not quite what I was looking for, but it works.